# Changes in inline JavaScript code requires a hard refresh before IE9 picks up it

Tags: javascript, jsf, caching, internet-explorer-9

We are using JSF on Facelets. Our JavaScript is written inline, not in an external `.js` file. In IE9 the user must do a hard refresh to see changes. It seems to be an IE9 issue as Chrome and IE11 (which corporate is rolling out soon) don't. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: So a small change in the 'html' part in the xhtml does result in IE9 pickiing the change up, but a change in the js part does not? JSF Version? Server info? Compatibility mode?

Comment: This is very unlikely a JSF problem as Facelet cache doesn't depend on user agent.

Comment: What's up with editing the question? The JavaScript is not inline. It's in a standard <script> tag, just in the xhtml file, not a js file.

Comment: WebLogic 12.1, JSF 2.1. Compatibility mode looks to be locked down.